# Como colocar a barrinha overflow no alto da tabela

Tags: php, html, css, table

Tenho uma tabela com um barrinha (`overflow-x`) pra rolar para os lados.

A barrinha está embaixo da tabela, mas gostaria que ela ficasse em cima. Consegui que a barrinha ficasse girando a tabela 360 graus e a barrinha 180 graus, mas deu um problema com um gráfico que está em um botão no fim da tabela.

Então, preciso colocar essa barrinha no alto da tabela de uma forma que não seja girando a tabela.

```
<?php

require 'conn.php';

//Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
$qry = mysqli_query($lnk, "select * from banco");

//Pegando os nomes dos campos
$num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry); //Obtém o número de campos do resultado

for($i = 0; $i < $num_fields ; $i++){ //Pega o nome dos campos
    $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry, $i)->name;
}

//$barrinha imprime aquela barrinha que tem no final da tabela.
$barrinha .= '<div class="table-table" style="overflow-x:scroll;">';
echo $barrinha;

//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-striped table-inverse"> <tr style="">';

for($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<th>' . $fields[$i] . '</th>';
}

// Montando o corpo da tabela
// Tá meio gambiarrado mas pelo menos funciona.

$table .= '<tbody>';

$vermelho_jan = 0;
$verde_jan = 0;
$vermelho_dez = 0;
$verde_dez = 0;

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)) {

    $table .= '<tr>';

    if ($r['ID'] > $r['ID']) {
        $table .= '<td>' . $r['ID'] . '</td>';
    } else {
        $table .= '<td>' . $r['ID'] . '</td>';
    }

    if ($r['KPI'] > $r['KPI']) {
        $table .= '<td style="font-weight:bolder; width:120px !important;">' . $r['KPI'] . '</td>';
    }else{
        $table .= '<td style="font-weight:bolder;">' . $r['KPI'] . '</td>';
    }

    if ($r['PILOTE'] > $r['PILOTE']) {
        $table .= '<td>' . $r['PILOTE'] . '</td>';
    } else {
        $table .= '<td>' . $r['PILOTE'] . '</td>';
    }

    //Aqui começam os meses
    if ($r['JAN_PREV'] > $r['JAN_REAL']) {
        $table .= '<td>' . $r['JAN_PREV'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '<td style="background:#ff4545;">' . $r['JAN_REAL'] . '</td>';
        $vermelho_jan += 1;
    } else {
        $table .= '<td>' . $r['JAN_PREV'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '<td style="background:#c3f786;">' . $r['JAN_REAL'] . '</td>';
        $verde_jan += 1;
    }

    if ($r['DEZ_PREV'] > $r['DEZ_REAL']) {
        $table .= '<td>' . $r['DEZ_PREV'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '<td >' . $r['DEZ_REAL'] . '</td>';
        $vermelho_dez += 1;
    } else {
        $table .= '<td>' . $r['DEZ_PREV'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '<td >' . $r['DEZ_REAL'] . '</td>';
        $verde_dez += 1;
    }


    $table .= '<div class="table-table" style="overflow-x:auto;">';

    // Adicionando botão de edição
    $table .= '<td><form action="qualite-edicao.php" method="post">'; 
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="' . $r['ID'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="KPI" value="' . $r['KPI'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="PILOTE" value="' . $r['PILOTE'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN PREV" value="' . $r['JAN_PREV'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN REAL" value="' . $r['JAN_REAL'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ PREV" value="' . $r['DEZ_PREV'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ REAL" value="' . $r['DEZ_REAL'] . '">';
    $table .= '<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></i> Editar </i></button>'; //
    $table .= '</form></td>';

    //MODAL COM OS GRÁFICOS
    $table .= '<td><form action="graf-qualite.php" method="post">'; 
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="' . $r['ID'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="KPI" value="' . $r['KPI'] . ' style="">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="PILOTE" value="' . $r['PILOTE'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN PREV" value="' . $r['JAN PREV'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN REAL" value="' . $r['JAN REAL'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ PREV" value="' . $r['DEZ PREV'] . '">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ REAL" value="' . $r['DEZ REAL'] . '">';
    $table .= '<!-- Button -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" name="button" onclick="abreModal(' . $r['ID'] .');">
                Gráfico
                </button>

                <!-- Modal -->

                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" onload="click("button");">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Gráfico</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
    $table .= '</form></td>';
}

$table .= '<tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="background-color:#c3f786; font-weight:bolder;">GREEN</td>
            <td style="background-color:#c3f786;"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">' . $verde_jan . '</td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">' . $verde_dez . '</td>
        </tr>';
$table .= '<tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="background-color:#ff4545; font-weight:bolder;">RED</td>
            <td style="background-color:#ff4545;"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">' . $vermelho_jan . '</td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight:bolder;">' . $vermelho_dez . '</td>
        </tr>';

//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

echo $table;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim fica o gráfico normalmente quando a barrinha está em baixo da tabela: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E assim fica o gráfico quando eu coloco a barrinha no alto da tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Serve uma solução usando jQuery?

Comment: Serve sim, se puder mostrar... :)

Comment: Ok! Dê uma olhada: https://jsfiddle.net/gvjo8qfd/

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem uma opção similar a [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330045/como-colocar-a-barra-de-rolagem-sobre-a-tabela), porém no meu exemplo o elemento não é rotacionado com `transform: rotate(180deg);` no meu caso eu usei `transform: scaleY(-1);` para "espelhar" o elemento no `eixo Y`. Pode ser que no seu caso resolva sem *buggar* o gráfico.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.wrapper,
.content {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="content">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
        <th>Header 5</th>
        <th>Header 6</th>
        <th>Header 7</th>
        <th>Header 8</th>
        <th>Header 9</th>
        <th>Header 10</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Então, o problema é que a tabela ficou de cabeça pra baixo.

Comment: Eu mesma fiz aquela pergunta, mas o problema é que a resposta dela não atende mais e eu não queria fechar ela porque pode ajudar muita gente.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Essa técnica que usei na minha resposta é diferente da outra, veja que na outra ele usa rotate(180deg), aqui eu usei scaleY(-1), no cade dele ele girou a tabela para ficar de cabeça para baixo, no meu caso eu "espelhei" a tabla. Olhe com atenção a minha resposta. A sua não deveria ficar de cabeça para baixo, pois o exemplo que está ai encima está certinho.... Acho que vc deixou de copiar alguma classe ou parte do CSS pro seu projeto... O principal é esse ponto: `.wrapper,
   .content {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
   }`

Comment: Primeiro: Desculpa, dei "resposta certa" antes de testar o gráfico. :/

Comment: Então, eu espelhei a tabela como você disse e espelhei o table-table também pra tabela não ficar ao contrário. Resolveu, mas dá problema no gráfico. Vou colocar na pergunta o problema que dá no gráfico.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira sem problemas, como falei eu não sei se espelhar em vez de rotacionar poderia resolver o problema do gráfico. Mas se vc testou e não resolveu ai é preciso buscar alguma outra solução... Tipo algum plugin que crie uma barra de rolagem usando JS ou jQuery. Se possível coloque um print de como o gráfico está ficando com o erro

Comment: Estava tentando ajustar o css do modal com o gráfico e percebi que esse modal tá aparecendo no centro da tabela como foi programado, só que esse centro virou canto quando a barra de rolagem foi puxada. A pergunta é: Por que isso não acontecia quando a barra estava em baixo já que a barra é puxada do mesmo jeito?

Comment: @MarianaFerreira sem acesso ao código para inspecionar os elementos não posso te dar uma certeza, mas acredito que esse modal do gráfico tenha algum CSS com `transform` para faze-lo centralizar na página. Mas quando vc tb usa `transform` no container que o gráfico está dentro ele deve estar "bagunçando" a referencia do gráfico, e ele está ficando alinha no meio da tabela e não no meio da janela alguma coisa assim...